# Accessing routes to server with React Router on production build?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just can't seem to access URLs to the server or backend once my react-router has been loaded. I can curl the requests like so to https://produktivv.com/api/testme - the same goes if you access this link without visiting the home page.

Basically, as soon as React is loaded in to the browser, it handles all URLs from there on in. Have even set up a reverse proxy, still no luck. It's a React thing.

All is working with axios requests to the server, I just can't seem to access it from the browser.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code for that route?

Comment: Just a simple request to express -  

app.get('/api/testme', (req,res) =>{
  console.log(123);
  res.send('Hello saul');
 });

Comment: Think I need to set the server up as a microservice then route all requests to the api.example.com url

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem. You have server routes and React Router routes set up but the server routes don't do anything?

Comment: Yeah. Ok, so I want to access this url in the browser - api/testme. I always want this route to hit the server. But for some reason when I load the site to a react URL, if I then try to access this URL it's a blank page cause the route isn't set up in React router.

Comment: It's basically for oAuth flow. I have a URL /auth/facebook which a user needs to hit the server with. This enables passport strategy. I want it to bypass the react router.

Comment: It seems as if React Router, Express Routing, and Axios are working as expected. Typically, React Router renders a view on the front end, from there Axios or a similar service will connect to the Express route and send data back and forth. Front-end routers like React Router are meant to keep users from directly calling routes to your back-end. Why not use Axios to serve as the middleground for passport?

Comment: Can you give a list of your server and React routes? It sounds like you might be missing something.

Comment: I still need to redirect them to the FaceBook login page for confirmation and then there's a callback URL which gives the user info. It's the only flow I know that works well. I see what you mean though.

Comment: <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
     <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
     <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
     <Route path="/social_auth" component={SocialAuthRedirect} />
     <Route exact path="/home" component={requireAuth(Home)} />
     <Route exact path="/daily" component={requireAuth(DailyJournal)} />

Comment: Can you capture that user info from the callback URL on the front end, and then send it to your backend to process the authentication. After that return the result to your front end. 

I know it seems like extra steps but then you aren't bypassing the intended functionality of React Router.

Comment: Haha probably :))) - I'll need to look. See it works fine on dev environment then you build it and it changes functionality. I blame Dan Abramov.